# Coefficient of friction between magnets

Tags: magnetic-fields, friction

Imagine two axially-magnetized ring-shaped permanent magnets in a repulsive configuration where one is levitating on top of the other (and somehow radially constrained so the PMs remain ~concentric). Once we start rotating the top PM, what is the coefficient of friction between the two magnets?

I imagine it's a non-zero number -- if so, what is the source of friction?  What does its magnitude depend on?

Answer (score 1):

It's zero, both definitionally (friction is a force between materials in contact, and they aren'tin contact) and practically, with friction being used as a catch all for dissipative forces. Neither the direction nor the magnitude of the magnetic field at any point on either ring is changing, so there are no induced electric fields and no induced currents that would dissipate mechanical energy as heat. With no induced electric field, and the sum of gravity and magnetic force zero everywhere, no work is done.

If the magnets are misaligned even a little bit by the constraints, then the rotation will induce current, which will encounter resistivity of the magnets; the magnets will warm up and slow down as a result. This process is distinct from friction but analogous to it.

There's a small drag force from air, unless we do the experiment in a vacuum, and presumably a friction force from whatever guide bars etc we've used to constrain the system of magnets, but neither of these are any different from doing the experiment with unmagnetized rings in free fall.

Comment: Thank you.  Is the implication of this that if the magnets were not arranged in a concentric manner, but rather in a coplanar manner (as in, when viewed from the side, they look like the number 8), and the top magnet was rotating, there would be lots of induced currents?

Comment: @MehranJ Yes, that's right.